# What causes renderingbugs with images in css 3d transforms?

Tags: css

I have created a 3d–carousel using css-transforms:
http://slotmashine.herokuapp.com/#/1/2

Only supported in chrome so far.

I experience fluttering and images disapearing alltogether. I have looked at similair projects that don't experience the same problems as I do. What can cause theese issues?

```
html, body{
    height: 100%
}

.button{
    position: absolute;
}
.spinner{
    -webkit-perspective: 800; /* For compatibility with iPhone 3.0, we leave off the units here */
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 225px;
}

.spinner>div{
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    float: left;
    -webkit-animation: spin 8s infinite linear;

}
    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
      from { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0); }
      to   { -webkit-transform: rotateX(-720deg); }
    }
.spinner>div>img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.spinner>div>img:nth-child(1){
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(700px);
    transform: translateZ(700px);
}
.spinner>div>img:nth-child(2){
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(51.42deg) translateZ(600px);
    transform: rotateX(51.42deg) translateZ(700px);
}
.spinner>div>img:nth-child(3){
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(102.85deg) translateZ(700px);
    transform: rotateX(102.85deg) translateZ(700px);
}
.spinner>div>img:nth-child(4){
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(154.28deg) translateZ(700px);
    transform: rotateX(154.28deg) translateZ(700px);
}
.spinner>div>img:nth-child(5){
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(205.71deg) translateZ(700px);
    transform: rotateX(205.71deg) translateZ(700px);
}
.spinner>div>img:nth-child(6){
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(257.14deg) translateZ(700px);
    transform: rotateX(257.14deg) translateZ(700px);
}
.spinner>div>img:nth-child(7){
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(308.57deg) translateZ(700px);
    transform:  rotateX(308.57deg) translateZ(700px);
}
```

Comment: would be nice if your could recreate it in a jsfiddle or jsbin or anywhere where we can play around with your code. besides, your link doesnt work in IE and doesnt look 3d at all on chrome...

Comment: You do not have a semicolon after height: 100% in your first CSS rule.